# post request never returning fetch api js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

Hello guys I'm trying to make a post request using js fetch api but the problem it's not returning. It never enters the callback in the then function. Can somebody tell me what is it that is going wrong

```
fetch('http://ready.buzlin.com/buzlinApp/checkout/checkout.php', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',

              },
              body: s
          }).then((response) => {
              console.log("ok");
          });
```

If I make the same call using postman it works

[image]

Comment: any error in `catch`?

Comment: If you look in the network inspector, does it show the request completing?

Comment: Does the API allow CORS?

Comment: @Ezekiel can you shed some light on what you shared

Comment: @Ezekiel Nothing wrong with the arrow function.

Comment: I am 99% sure this is a `CORS` issue

Comment: @AyushGupta but in postman no cors error are coming

Comment: @Gardezi postman does NOT check for cors, chrome does, see if there is any error in the console

Comment: @AyushGupta the problem is I'm working on react native so I can't see anything in the console :(

Comment: what are the incoming headers in postman?

Comment: @AyushGupta https://imgur.com/a/YLWJh

Comment: @Gardezi make the request outside reactjs, then if it pulls through, you know it has nothing to do with your request. Also is the request meant to update a reactjs state?

Comment: @Ezekiel yes but not atm. but yes it will

Comment: @Gardezi so did the fetch api pull through outside reactjs? If no did you check your console to be able to debug?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem, a security measure adopted by browsers (which explains why you could do it via Postman).

Basically, your browser sends a preflight request to the server to know what it is expecting, and the server isn't returning your origin as an acceptable one (Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header).

This API probably does not support CORS. That means your request will only work if made from server-side, secure browsers will not allow it.